Using pandas I'm trying to split fullname into two new columns, first_name and last_name
I'm trying to split a column titled fullname into first and last names. I'm using the following code. However, the last name does not work for me when I have a name like mary van der smith. van der smith should be captured as the last name but I'm not certain how to do this. In the code below I just receive smith.
df['first_name'] = df['full_name'].str.split().str[0]
df['last_name'] = df['full_name'].str.split().str[-1]

Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

What if the name is mary elizabeth van der smith? There is no easy/magic generic method to split names.

Welcome to SO. Does this answer your question? Pandas: how to split or extract multiple values from column. str.extract seems like what you want (in a much simpler version than what is detailed in the linked post). I use it all the time.

Instead of trying to get the last name using index, you can use slicing. Slicing allows you to extract the second string position to the end, effectively capturing the last name without using the index value. Finally you can join them together using the "join()" method to form one string.
df['first_name'] = df['full_name'].str.split().str[0]
df['last_name'] = df['full_name'].str.split().str[1:].str.join(' ')


If really this is what OP wants, then better df[['first_name', 'last_name']] = df['full_name'].str.split(n=1, expand=True) would be much more efficient. But as commented above, this won't work if a first name has several words.

Thank you Chukwudi To-Anadu. That worked!
Thank you as well mozway!

You can do it in one call: pd.Series.str.extract lets you operate a split and assign to a number of columns, without having to repeat the command for the second part of the name. This might represent a gain in execution time, depending on your data size.
# Input sample
df = pd.DataFrame({'full_name' : ['user 24012259', 
                                  'John Doe', 
                                  'John Fitzgerald Kennedy']})
# One-liner split
df[['name','surname']] = df['full_name'].str.extract(pat='^(.*)\s(.*)$')

# Output
                 full_name             name   surname
0            user 24012259             user  24012259
1                 John Doe             John       Doe
2  John Fitzgerald Kennedy  John Fitzgerald   Kennedy

Where the '^(.*)\s(.*)$' regular expression seeks 2 groups separated by a space. As @mozway pointed out, beyond the simple 'name surname' case, this may not produce the output you expect. If you need to elaborate on this, please post a representative input sample.
References:
This was already exemplified in

Python: Extract dimension data from dataframe string column and create columns with values for each of them
Substring extraction with pandas / regex
or Pandas: how to split or extract multiple values from column although each with a slightly more complex patterns (e.g. splitting one column into three)

